# Rust matches! macro different return value depending on if value is in variable or not

Tags: rust, macros

I have this piece of code:

```
fn main() {
    let x = Some(1);
    let y = Some(2);
    println!("{}",matches!(x,y));
    println!("{}",matches!(x,Some(2)));
}
```

that prints `true` and `false`
I would expect it to return false two time,because the values of `Some` are different. What is the reason behind this behaviour? Is y shadowed somehow under the hood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the reason behind this behaviour? Is y shadowed somehow under the hood?

Yes, this introduces a new binding `y` which will match anything. This code produces warnings indicating that neither `y` is used:

```
warning: unused variable: `y`
 --> src/main.rs:3:9
  |
3 |     let y = Some(2);
  |         ^ help: if this is intentional, prefix it with an underscore: `_y`
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default

warning: unused variable: `y`
 --> src/main.rs:4:30
  |
4 |     println!("{}",matches!(x,y));
  |                              ^ help: if this is intentional, prefix it with an underscore: `_y`
```

This is akin to [Why is this match pattern unreachable when using non-literal patterns?](/q/28225958/2189130) but in a slightly different form. Here, `matches!(x,y)` is equivalent to this (see [source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/macros/mod.rs.html#429) for `matches!`):

```
match x {
    y => true,
    _ => false,
}
```

Identifiers are used to create new bindings in patterns (unless they are constants) and thus do not use the variable with that name.